# "Sub-windows" in CentOS 7.4 GNOME flashes then disappears

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, gnome3

After updating to CentOS 7.4, I have been experiencing some issues with sub-windows (not sure if that is the correct term). Let me explain.

Take for instance the Wacom Control Panel. Everything there works really well.. I can tweak the settings, and do all I need to do. However, the moment I click 'Calibrate', which should open an overlay on the screen where I click some targets to calibrate the stylus properly, it doesn't open. The only thing that happens is a rectangle appears on the bottom panel with the title 'gnome-control-center' as if there is a window that is going to open, then it quickly disappears.

The same issue happens also in another program I use.. DaVinci Resolve... the timeline view options in that program is supposed to open a small screen overlay where I change the settings... The moment I click it, it flashes on the screen really quickly, then disappears.

This doesn't happen with every single sub-window, as there are other sub-windows in both the Wacom Control Panel and DaVinci Resolve that open without any problem.

However, it is also not a specific issue for one program.

Additionally, I am sure this is a GNOME only issue, because I have tried CentOS KDE, and I don't have the same problem there. The only problem is I won't be able to use KDE, as it presents a different set of issues that probably will be harder to tackle. Therefore, it would be easier for me to stick with GNOME and try finding a solution to this one problem I am having.

Have anyone encountered a similar issue OR does anyone have any idea how I can fix it?